# How to cite a journal paper which do not have a page number?

Tags: publications, citations, journals, paper-submission, bibtex

I was very annoyed with the Elsevier's journals. Many of them do not provide the page number of the paper.

For example, see, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168420302176

You can not find any page number, expcept a weird seris of numbers "Volume 176, November 2020, 107674".

Should I use that "107674" as the page number? (**If I do this in bibtex , it would looke like pp. 107674**)

Comment: Yes, that's normal, and 107674 is the page number.

Comment: Or should it should be issue number?

Comment: Why does it matter anyway? I find it lot easier to track down papers using title and author names rather than journal issue and page number.

Comment: @Vibex it matters to formality

Comment: If it's a formatting requirement you can just use 107674 and don't have to worry about it further. My point is that you are probably overthinking this because readers will usually use other information to track down the paper (DOI, title, year etc.) before resorting to page numbers.

Comment: @Vibex Yes, I totally understand. It is the reviewer complaining about it without giving any solutions.

Comment: On the page you linked, go to "Export"  and export the citation to your favorite reference manager. (You are using a reference manager, aren't you? If not, start using one.)

Comment: @Vibex, people are different. I use page numbers all the time to find papers from references...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially that number seems to be called *Article Number* (see the [Table of Contents of Vol. 176](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/signal-processing/vol/176/suppl/C) of that journal; the journal seems to have switched from 'page numbers' to 'article numbers' with Vol. 166).

It nevertheless seems safe to call it the *page* number. The reason is that Elsevier itself deposited that 'article number' as the 'page'-metadata in CrossRef (a depository for research papers' metadata).

See here: http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1016/j.sigpro.2020.107674, where it says:
`"page":"107674"`

Comment: Website like CrossRef or Google Scholar uses web spider to crawl data from the internet automatically. As a web developer, I do not think we should directly use the provided metadata, as they might be wrong.